# Unwanted space is found in Xamarin UWP app's ContentView

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I've been having a trouble with unwanted extra space in Xamarin UWP app's ContentView

```
  <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
  <Grid RowSpacing="0">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <!--Header - Logo & Caption-->
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
     <!--ListView menu with boxes-->
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
     <!--Footer-->
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   ...
```

Below my ListView, I get to see a lot of unwanted space. I tried Auto and * options but I'm still getting space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Star sizing that divides available space using a weighted factor.

For example:

```xml
<Grid RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--Header - Logo & Caption-->
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <!--ListView menu with boxes-->
                <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
                <!--Footer-->
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="header" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lv">

            </ListView>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="footer" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```